# Grant or granting of rights?

Tags: grammar

Good morning!

How can I refer to the conferral of rights on citizens? As the grant or the granting of rights?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, `grant` is the natural noun of language (as well as the verb), `granting` is the result of the action, the gerund form, as mentioned [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/234710/grant-or-granting-of-rights/234714?noredirect=1#comment445447_234714) (what has the same meaning of the noun).

However, when it comes from advocacy wide usage of language, even [grant of rights](https://www.lawinsider.com/clause/grant-of-rights) as [granting of rights](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/granting-of-rights) seems to be pretty common. Thus comprehend which [conferral of right on citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_conferral) wanted you to refer, I would say that both alternatives are the same right.

Comment: Likely "meaning of the noun." *Granting* is the present participle of the verb *to grant*, and that form will be noted in most dictionaries. Like most present participles it can take the role of a noun (in which case, it's called gerund), and it means the act of one who grants, which is different from a grant, which is the result of granting.  As far as I know, *granting* has no special meaning (unlike say, *saying* or *icing*), so it won't be listed separately in a dictionary.